# Drupal 8 - How to create 4 different types of blog posts

Tags: drupal, drupal-8

I am tasked with creating a blog with Drupal 8. There are 4 potential different blog post formats. Each type has different layouts and different potential fields of information. I think I would need to create one content type of 'Blog Post' but then need some way to allow the user to select different field (or sets of fields) to be able to construct the post as designed.

For example:

**Blog post type 1:**
article title
1x2 tables to split top 10 in 2 sets
2nd title
Full width graphic
third title
article
side bar with title and table
block with background graphic with youtube video and text to the right

**Blog post type 2**
title
graphic
1 x 3 grey blocks with title and text
graphic

**Blog post type 3**
title
article
right sidebar with text

I think they need to be the same content type since I also need to pull them all together for a 3x2x3 thumbnail list on the homepage.

Problem is I have no idea how to create the different types of blog type and, then, how to create the design 'page' to show each correctly.

Any advice on how to start to structure this project would be greatly appreciated.

Sorry to ask, but I am still new to Drupal 8.

Comment: Either create multiple "blog" content types. or create 1 "blog" content type and use the [paragraphs module](https://www.drupal.org/project/paragraphs) to allow the user to select different field types

Answer (score 1):

It is quite easy.

- Install Page Manager module to create different layouts to your content type Blog
- Install term_condition module
- Create field taxonomy_term blog_type in your CT to select Blog Type
- In Your Page Manager Variant create 3 additional Variants, one per your blog type and select this type in Selection Criteria Tab
- Use Form API States [Doc](https://www.lullabot.com/articles/form-api-states) or module like conditional states to hide or show your different fields per blog type :)
  [image]